# "Navigate away" comes up when I haven't actually edited anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

> **Note**: From the comments, it appears this is not a feature-request, but a bug isolated to Firefox.

The confirm popup that saves you from losing your work when leaving the edit page...

> You have started writing or editing a post.
>
> Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.

... seems to be pretty smart about not coming up when you didn't really edit anything. But, in Firefox there is one small problem.

It seems to use some type of keypress detection to trigger the "modified" state.  I frequently open the edit window to copy some raw text and paste it somewhere else.  Other browsers only detect actually entry keys, but I'm getting the popup after simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

Then, when I close the window or click back, I have to dismiss the popup before continuing.  It's not a huge inconvenience, but thanks to some genius in the browser cabal, I can *never* get used to "OK" being the same as "throw away my work", so it takes a split second of thought.

---

*Browser: Firefox 3.6, Mac OS X*

Comment: Browser/OS? I'm not getting this issue on IE8 on XP. I can `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+C` your question here and navigate away without error. If I so much as input a character in the body prior to hitting `Ctrl+A` (your standard "I hit Z while reaching for Shift!" kind of scenario), though, it'll immediately stop me.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 10.0.648.205

Comment: Interesting - I added my platform details to the question. I can do it even with Ctrl+A alone.

Comment: Sorry for the bad answer!  I done torched it.

Comment: @squillman: Firefox 4 shows a generic prompt in the confirmation dialog, not the prompt that the site gives it; hence your confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the next build, the confirmation dialog is only shown if the content actually has changed (which certainly makes more sense than only basing it on "has a key been pressed?").

Your issue is fixed as a side effect of this change, since pressing Ctrl-A (or anyting) alone doesn't suffice to trigger the dialog anymore.

Comment: I somehow missed this answer, probably in one of those super-collider multi-notification moments.  But thanks!  My original post was as a feature request, but then when others reported they didn't have the same problem, I wondered if it was just a bug.  Anyway, this is the change I hoped for.